# Creating class with parameter constructor in Scala reflection

Tags: scala, reflection

I have a class that may take from 1 to 4 parameters. They are always Strings. I would like to create an object of this class based on the number of arguments passed to the function. Is there any way to go around having to create constructor and passing an array of Objects directly to newInstance?

```
NewInstanceWithReflection clazz = (NewInstanceWithReflection)Class.forName("NewInstanceWithReflection").newInstance();
Constructor constructor = NewInstanceWithReflection.class.getDeclaredConstructor( new Class[] {String.class});
NewInstanceWithReflection object1 = (NewInstanceWithReflection)clazz.newInstance(new Object[]{"StackOverFlow"});
```

This code pasted into sbt interpreter does not seem to work. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You got it all wrong (not to mention, it's java syntax, not scala).
Something like this should work in scala:

```
  classOf[NewInstanceWithReflection]
    .getDeclaredConstructor(classOf[String])
    .newInstance("StackOverFlow")
```

And this is what you'd need in java:

```
  NewInstanceWithReflection
    .class
    .getDeclaredConstructor(String.class)
    .newInstance("StackOverFlow")
```

Comment: Sorry, I've screwed up my code example. I just wanted to know whether or not is it possible to skip the `.getDeclaredConstructor(classOf[String])`, because the amount of String args may vary from 1 to 4 and just pass the dynamic number of args to `newInstance` method.

Comment: no, it's not possible ... `newInstance` is a method on the `Constructor` object. You need to have the object in order to call a method on it. So, "skipping" getting of the the object instance is not going to work.